# maven-dependency-analyzer unable to process some classes

Tags: java, maven

I am using an osgi plugin that internally calls maven-dependency-analyzer for scanning bytecode class files.
However, it throws IndexOutOfBoundException for some classes.
And it points to this code
https://github.com/apache/maven-dependency-analyzer/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/shared/dependency/analyzer/asm/DependencyClassFileVisitor.java#L83
[image]
Any idea how can I resolved this issue? Should I use any other asm depenency?

Comment: Which version of dependency analyzer is being used?

Comment: 1.1 of maven-dependency-analyzer

Comment: I would say it's a bit out of date: please check https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-dependency-analyzer/